# Replacing place holders with letter in Hangman C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Right now I am currently making a Hangman game in C++. My current trouble is that I have a string that replaces the randomly selected word from the file and replaces it with "*'s". Unfortunately my code isn't replacing them with the correct letters/word guessed, I have checked with breakpoints what the word is. PLEASE IGNORE THE HANGMAN DRAWING FOR NOW UNLESS YOU HAVE POINTERS ON HOW TO EXECUTE IT IN THIS PROGRAM. Any help would be appreciated.
My text file has the following words in it:
apple
orange
car
truck
bicycle
cat
dog
snake
rock
sock
blue
red
color

My code is as follows:

```
int wordFill(char guess, string theWordSecret, string&guessWord) //function for determing if you guess a letter contained
{
    int i;
    int hits = 0; //letter hits within the word
    int many = theWordSecret.length();

    for (i = 0; i < hits; i++)
    {
        if (guess == guessWord[i])
            return 0;
        if (guess == theWordSecret[i])
        {
            guessWord[i] == guess;
            hits++;
        }
    }
    return hits;
}
```

Comment: Is there any need to dump all that code? A minimal example should illustrate exactly which part of the code you are having a problem with.

Comment: I only did that large portion to see if maybe the problem could be contained within another portion of the code.

Comment: I am trying to help you. Less is more. If you dump lots of irrelevant code who can be bothered to read it?

Comment: If you are willing to help I will send you the code that I am most concerned about. int wordFill(char guess, string theWordSecret, string&guessWord) //function for determing if you guess a letter contained
{
 int i;
 int hits = 0; //letter hits within the word
 int many = theWordSecret.length();

 for (i = 0; i < hits; i++)
 {
  if (guess == guessWord[i])
   return 0;
  if (guess == theWordSecret[i])
  {
   guessWord[i] == guess;
   hits++;
  }
 }
 return hits;
}

Comment: just edit your question!

Comment: And edited. I'm not sure if that will be enough to go off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters inside the wordFill function the for loop should say

```
for (i = 0; i < many; i++)
```

Instead of

```
for (i = 0; i < hits; i++)
```

To replace the asterisks in the mystery add the following code if the user guesses a correct letter

```
for (int replace = 0; replace < mystery.length(); replace++)
{
    if (theWord[replace] == letter)
    {
        mystery[replace] = letter;
    }
}
```

That should solve all your problems (for now).

Comment: Where should I put that exactly? My teammate just figured that many part out as you posted that.

Comment: The second part of the code I posted belongs in your main function within the 2nd while loop in the else statement. Line 60 to be specific

Answer (score 1):

As Rafi pointed out you are comparing `i < hits` which of course is equivalent to `i < 0`

Also note that your line of code:

`guessWord[i] == guess;`

is not an assignment: it is a *comparison* - beware of `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Thanks for y'alls help. It helped a lot. We are now one step closer to finished.

Comment: @Eric Jesse Good. Please award a tick to Rafi for answering your question and give him some credit and upvote any answers that actually helped you. Finally, please read this completely before posting your next question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask